# Linker error: Undefined reference C++

Tags: c++

I'm having this *undefined reference* error which i don't have no clue where it is coming from:

```
/usr/local/clion-2017.1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/jscherman/CLionProjects/algo3-tp3-cmf/cmake-build-debug --target experimentos -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target experimentos
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/experimentos.dir/experimentos.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable experimentos
CMakeFiles/experimentos.dir/experimentos.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/jscherman/CLionProjects/algo3-tp3-cmf/experimentos.cpp:12: undefined reference to `cmfExacto(int, int, std::__cxx11::list<Eje, std::allocator<Eje> >&)'
/home/jscherman/CLionProjects/algo3-tp3-cmf/experimentos.cpp:13: undefined reference to `heuristicaConstructiva(int, std::__cxx11::list<Eje, std::allocator<Eje> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/experimentos.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'experimentos' failed
make[3]: *** [experimentos] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/experimentos.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/experimentos.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/experimentos.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/experimentos.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'experimentos' failed
make: *** [experimentos] Error 2
```

experimentos.cpp(target)

```
#include "cmf-algo-exacto.h"
#include "cmf-heuristica-constructiva-golosa.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n = 5, m = 10;
    std::list<Eje> grafo = Utils::generarGrafo(n, m, false, 0, 0);
    std::cout << "Exacto: " << cmfExacto(n, m, grafo) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Constructiva: " << heuristicaConstructiva(n, grafo) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

cmf-heuristica-constructiva-golosa.h

```
#ifndef TEST_DEBUGGER_CMF_HEURISTICA_CONSTRUCTIVA_GOLOSA_H
#define TEST_DEBUGGER_CMF_HEURISTICA_CONSTRUCTIVA_GOLOSA_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Clique.h"
#include "Eje.h"
#include "DisjointSet.h"
#include <list>
#include "stringTokenizer.hpp"
#include "Utils.h"
#include <fstream>

Clique heuristicaConstructiva(int n, std::list<Eje> &listaIncidencias);
Clique hconstructiva(int n, std::list<int> *listaAdyacencias);

#endif //TEST_DEBUGGER_CMF_HEURISTICA_CONSTRUCTIVA_GOLOSA_H
```

---

cmf-heuristica-constructiva.cpp

```
#include "cmf-heuristica-constructiva-golosa.h"

Clique hconstructiva(int n, std::list<int> *listaAdyacencias){
    ...
}

Clique heuristicaConstructiva(int n, std::list<Eje> listaIncidencias) {
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

---

cmf-algo-exacto.h

```
#ifndef TEST_DEBUGGER_CMF_ALGO_EXACTO_H
#define TEST_DEBUGGER_CMF_ALGO_EXACTO_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Clique.h"
#include "Eje.h"
#include "DisjointSet.h"
#include <list>
#include "stringTokenizer.hpp"
#include "Utils.h"
#include <fstream>

Clique * cmfExacto(DisjointSet &uds, std::list<Eje> ejesNoAgregados, list<int> *listaAdyacencias);

Clique * cmfExacto(int n, int m, std::list<Eje> &listaIncidencias);

#endif //TEST_DEBUGGER_CMF_ALGO_EXACTO_H
```

---

cmf-algo-exacto.cpp

```
#include "cmf-algo-exacto.h"

Clique * cmfExacto(int n, int m, std::list<Eje> &listaIncidencias) {
   ...
}

Clique * cmfExacto(DisjointSet &uds, std::list<Eje> ejesNoAgregados, list<int> *listaAdyacencias){
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

So, as i understand the compiler is yelling that it is not finding those *cmfExacto* and *heuristicaConstructiva* functions but i can't see the problem. What is wrong here?

Comment: Divide and conquer.

Comment: @RSahu say what?

Comment: You have declared, and are calling, a function `Clique heuristicaConstructiva(int n, std::list<Eje>& listaIncidencias);` that takes its last parameter by reference. But you've never implemented that function. You have implemented a different, unrelated function `Clique heuristicaConstructiva(int n, std::list<Eje> listaIncidencias)` that takes its last parameter by value, but you aren't calling it. Similarly with `cmfExacto(int n, int m, std::list<Eje> &listaIncidencias)`

Comment: Two main functions?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are really compiling all the cpp files?
Looks like your CMake / compiler isn't including `cmf-algo-exacto.cpp` and `cmf-heuristica-constructiva.cpp`.

Also, with those files, you may get errors since you define the `main` function multiple times. Best approach would probably be to create a separate `main.cpp` file and put the (only) `main` function there.

EDIT: Igor Tandetnik is right, the parameters don't match

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm ashamed i couldn't see that problem beforehand. This problem is because i forgot compiling those .cpp files. As you said, i'm now having problems with those main functions now.